# Selecting from multiple many to many relationshipes

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hi i have this [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOh5S.png) and i'm trying to select all programs (courses) that Employee can take and there types and sub types  base on the PROGRAM SPECIFICATION which is the Employee JOB and POSITION and DEPARTMENT and UNIT and SECTION
so i'm trying to select all the program for the employee that have the PROGRAM SPECIFICATION number 7
but when i'm trying to do that like this :

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ProgramSpecification]
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails] ON [dbo].[ProgramSpecification].PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID = [dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails].PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[Programs] ON [dbo].[Programs].ProgramID=[dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails].ProgramID 
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramSubTypesAndProgram] ON [dbo].[Programs].ProgramID = [dbo].[ProgramSubTypesAndProgram].ProgramID
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes].ProgramSubTypeID =  [dbo].[ProgramSubTypesAndProgram].ProgramSubTypeID
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramTypeAndSubType] ON [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes].ProgramSubTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramTypeAndSubType].ProgramSubTypeID
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramsTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramsTypes].ProgeamTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramTypeAndSubType].ProgeamTypeID
```

the expected result is :

```
PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID POSITION_ID POSITION    JOB_ID  JOB DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME UNIT_ID UNIT_NAME   SECTION_ID  SECTION_NAME    ProgramID   PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID ProgramID   ProgramName ProgramSubTypeID    ProgramID   ProgramSubTypeID    ProgramSubTypeName  ProgeamTypeID   ProgramSubTypeID    ProgeamTypeID   ProgramTypeName NominationTypeID
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    1   7   1   Corporate Culture   1   1   1   General 1   1   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    2   7   2   Business Etiquette  1   2   1   General 1   1   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    3   7   3   Technical Awareness 2   3   2   TC  1   2   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    4   7   4   Information Security For non Technical People   3   4   3   IS  1   3   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    18  7   18  Supply Chain Management 11  18  11  Procurement 2   11  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    33  7   33  Hyperion Financial Management   13  33  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    35  7   35  Oracle Financial Applications Overview  13  35  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    36  7   36  IFRS    13  36  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    116 7   116 The 7 Habits    41  116 41  Achievement Orientation 4   41  4   CompetencyBased 1
```

but instead it return the result like this

```
PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID POSITION_ID POSITION    JOB_ID  JOB DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME UNIT_ID UNIT_NAME   SECTION_ID  SECTION_NAME    ProgramID   PROGRAM_SPECIFCATION_ID ProgramID   ProgramName ProgramSubTypeID    ProgramID   ProgramSubTypeID    ProgramSubTypeName  ProgeamTypeID   ProgramSubTypeID    ProgeamTypeID   ProgramTypeName NominationTypeID
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    1   7   1   Corporate Culture   1   1   1   General 1   1   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    1   7   1   Corporate Culture   1   1   1   General 3   1   3   Business-Technical  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    1   7   1   Corporate Culture   1   1   1   General 5   1   5    Leadership 2
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    2   7   2   Business Etiquette  1   2   1   General 1   1   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    2   7   2   Business Etiquette  1   2   1   General 3   1   3   Business-Technical  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    2   7   2   Business Etiquette  1   2   1   General 5   1   5    Leadership 2
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    3   7   3   Technical Awareness 2   3   2   TC  1   2   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    4   7   4   Information Security For non Technical People   3   4   3   IS  1   3   1   Business-Awareness  1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    18  7   18  Supply Chain Management 11  18  11  Procurement 2   11  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    33  7   33  Hyperion Financial Management   13  33  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    35  7   35  Oracle Financial Applications Overview  13  35  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    36  7   36  IFRS    13  36  13  Finance 2   13  2   Business-Specialized    1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    116 7   116 The 7 Habits    41  116 41  Achievement Orientation 4   41  4   CompetencyBased 1
7   12424   Account Payable Accountant  48  Accountant  587 Finance 650 Accounting  582 Account Payables    116 7   116 The 7 Habits    42  116 42  Adaptability    4   42  4   CompetencyBased 1
```

in the line 2 3 5 6 it return the same program for different program type knowing that the wanted result is just the one with the `ProgramTypeName` Business-Awareness and `ProgramSubTypeName` General but 
because the `ProgramType` and `ProgramSubType` have many to many relationship  it return all the `ProgramType` that have  the `ProgramSubType` General knowing that the PROGRAM SPECIFICATION number 7 it need to be link with (selected) withe the  `ProgramTypeName` Business-Awareness and `ProgramSubTypeName` General

and the same thing in the last line 14 it but instead of  `ProgramType` here the tow tables are `Programs` and `ProgramSubType` that have the many to many relationship so it return in the result all the ProgramName that have the same `ProgramID` with different `ProgramSubTypeID` knowing that the wanted result for PROGRAM SPECIFICATION number 7  is just the Program with `ProgramID` 116 and   `ProgramSubTypeID` 41
so please any help on how can i do that and many thanks in advance.

Comment: in such scenerio you always use ranking function with partition by,most probably row_number()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my db schema to be like this [image: db schema] and then use this tow query's to 
VIEW ALL PROGRAMS AND THERE DETAILS  and VIEW ALL PROGRAMS THAT ARE AVAILABLE FOR A POSITION

VIEW ALL PROGRAMS AND THERE DETAILS:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Programs]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramDetails] ON [dbo].[Programs].ProgramID =  [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes].ProgramSubTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramSubTypeID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramsTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramsTypes].ProgramTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramTypeID
```

VIEW ALL PROGRAMS THAT ARE AVAILABLE FOR A POSITION:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Positions] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails] ON [dbo].[Positions].PositionID =  [dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails].PositionID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramDetails] ON [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramDetailsID = [dbo].[ProgramsSpecificationDetails].ProgramDetailsID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Programs] ON [dbo].[Programs].ProgramID =  [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramSubTypes].ProgramSubTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramSubTypeID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProgramsTypes] ON [dbo].[ProgramsTypes].ProgramTypeID = [dbo].[ProgramDetails].ProgramTypeID
```

and it give the wanted results

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two many-to-many relations - tables ProgramSubTypesAndProgram and ProgramTypeAndSubType you have to change your db schema to get single results, eg. adding exact Type to Program relation table ProgramSubTypesAndProgram or making Type-SubType relation only one-to-many.